# State not set with jest mock

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

Component code:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            validAuthCode: true,
        }
    }

    async handleAuthentication(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        try {
            let validAuthCode = await createPermanentAuth(this.state.authCode);
            if (validAuthCode) {
                this.props.history.push("/");
            }
            this.setState({ validAuthCode: false });
        } catch(e) {
            // error handling
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleAuthentication.bind(this)} data-testid="create-permanent-auth">
                <label htmlFor="code">Auth code:</label>
                <input id="code"
                    name="code" 
                    placeholder="12345" 
                    className={this.state.validAuthCode ? 'valid-data' : 'invalid-data'}
                    onChange={this.handleAuthCodeChange.bind(this)} />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
        );
    }
```

Test:

```
jest.mock('../yasClient');
.
. 
import { createPermanentAuth } from '../yasClient';

beforeEach(() => {
    token = screen.getByLabelText('Auth code:');
    
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
});


it("shows authcode outlined in red and error message displayed, when bad token entered.", () => {
    createPermanentAuth.mockReturnValueOnce(false);

    fireEvent.change(token, {  target: { value: '1' } });
    fireEvent.submit(screen.getByTestId('create-permanent-auth'));

    expect(createPermanentAuth).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(token.classList.contains('invalid-data')).toBe(true);
    expect(screen.getByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('visible')).toBe(true);
});
```

Looks like `validAuthCode` doesn't get set to false, for whatever reason.

`token.classList.contains('valid-data')` returns true, and I'd expect `token.classList.contains('invalid-data')` to return true.

I'm wondering whether I'm missing something. I'm guessing the problem may have something to do with asynchronicity and/or how setState is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up paying somebody on codementor to get this answer.

Test case

```
it("navigates to '/', when a good token is entered.", async() => {
    createPermanentAuthSpy.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(true));
    await act(async() => {
        await fireEvent.change(token, {  target: { value: '1' } });
        fireEvent.submit(screen.getByTestId('create-permanent-auth'));
    });

    expect(createPermanentAuthSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(token.classList.contains('valid-data')).toBe(true);
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
});
```

beforeEach

```
beforeEach(() => {    
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    
    act(() => {
        render(
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={TokenEntryWithRouter} />
            </Router>, 
            { wrapper: Wrapper }
        );
    });

    createPermanentAuthSpy = jest.spyOn(yasClient, "createPermanentAuth");
    token = screen.getByLabelText('Auth code:');
    
    expect(screen.queryByTestId('bad-code-message').classList.contains('hidden')).toBe(true);
});
```

I'm not sure what the difference is between the mocking techniques I had and this - but it works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap update state in act like this fire event :

```
await act(async()=>{
     await fireEvent.change(token, {  target: { value: '1' } });
     fireEvent.submit(screen.getByTestId('create-permanent-auth'));
 })
await act(async ()=>Promise.reslove())
```

this make sure that you are testing real behavior.
note: here  i added `await` for `fireEvent` on token component because  i don't want the button to fire `submit event` before token event update state.

Comment: Updated version https://pastebin.com/VhbWVKkD. Same error.

Comment: does the submit button call any `async` actions??

Comment: handleAuthentication, which is marked as asynchronous, gets called on submit.

Comment: ok so  did you mock the `api` call for the function ??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The API call within handleAuthentication is hopefully mocked well; see the first line in the test. handleAuthentication isn't

Comment: you need to resolve the promise after submit try adding the edited code above. plus if you add a code sandbox for your code so i can help you better.